# Can't get form option selected during a loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, select

I have a parser that stores values into variables (duh). The variable in question here is:

```
$item[2]   <- contains the string 'facebook'
```

I have an html form which contains a select menu. The menu is populated dynamically based on what is stored in my database. This is how my menu gets built:

```
<?php
$formats = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE taxonomy = 'format'
        "));
?>

<div id="format" class="form">
    Format: <?php echo $item[2]; ?>  <!-- echoes the variable to know it works -->
    <?php
        $terms = array();              
        foreach($formats as $key => $term){
            $terms[$term->parent][$term->term_id] = $term;
        }
    ?>    
    <select name="formats">
        <option value="empty"></option>
        <?php printTerms($terms, $item); ?> <!--- THIS DOESN'T APPEAR TO PASS $item INTO THE FUNCTION -->
    </select>
</div>

<?php
function printTerms($terms, $item, $parent = 0, $deep = 0){ // HOW DO I USE $item ???
    if(count($terms[$parent]) > 0){
        $indent = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $deep; $i++){
            $indent .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }

        foreach($terms[$parent] as $key => $term){
            if(count($terms[$term->term_id]) > 0){
                if($deep == 0){
                    echo "<option class='toplevel' value='".$term->name."' ".$selected.">".$term->name."</option>";   //     <- Outputs top level parents
                } else {
                    echo "<option class='child".$deep."' value='".$term->name."' ".$selected.">".$indent.$term->name."</option>";  // <- Outputs children that are also parents
                }

                printTerms($terms, $term->term_id, ($deep+1));

            } else {
                echo "<option class='solo' value='".$term->name."' ".$selected.">".$indent.$term->name."</option>";   // <- outputs bottom level children and solos.
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So far this all works but here's my problem.

I want to make it so that if items[2] contains the string 'Facebook' (which it does), that the corresponding menu option is selected by default.

I did get it to work in a simple static select menu like this:

```
foreach ($formats as $format) {
    $selected = '';
            if ($item[2] == 'facebook' || $item[2] == 'wall' && $format->slug == 'facebook'){ 
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo "<option value='".$format->name."' ".$selected.">".$format->name."</option>";
}
```

$format->slug is what contains the value I want to match to $item[2].
As such, $term->slug corresponds to $format->slug.

$format->name is the title of the select option for output into the menu itself.
Likewise, $term->name corresponds to $format->name.

$formats accesses this MySQL table:

```
term_id       name           slug                 taxonomy     parent
1             Entry Form     entry-form           format       0
2             Page           page                 format       3
3             Facebook       facebook             format       0
4             Entry Form     facebook-entry-form  format       3
5             Twitter        twitter              format       0
6             Single        single                format       2
```

You'll notice that I have already inserted the $selected variable into my function. My problem is that I can't get my code above to work inside the context of the printTerms function.

For the purposes of my question, assume that there is no whitespace whatsoever in any variables (I checked).

Some rules to keep in mind:

$term->slug and $item[2] do not always match. If $item[2] is 'wall' this should also result in a default selection for 'facebook'. (see my code above).

So the question is, how do I combine my printTerms() function with my select code?

Comment: Have you tried passing $item into printTerms and then if($term->name == $item[2]) { $selected='selected' }?

Comment: Right, forgot to pass $item into the function. That said, your suggestion doesn't work. I need to state if($item[2] == 'facebook' && $term->slug == 'facebook') {$selected='selected';} because $item[2] and $term->slug don't always match. I've tried your solution everywhere I could and didn't get it to work.

Comment: If you're doing recursion and want to space or otherwise compound a value, you can pass the initial and the current, so you don't have a `for` in a recursive walk. It could be that you need to `trim(strtolower($item[0])) == trim($term-slug))` to equalize the check and remove any unseen whitespace. It might help to see the *exact whitespace and all* output of the select pasted into the answer as a code block, as well.

Comment: You're right that if I am trying to get a child option to be selected that I would need to trim the whitespace. However the code won't work even for a parent option which has no whitespace. In my case, there is no whitespace whatsoever in either $item[2] or $term->slug.

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly modified your code to work without database, for testing. The real "change" is that I modified the `count()` to use `isset()` instead.

Trivial changes are that the options are now linefeed-separated and the function does not output anything, but returns the output instead.

The HTML thus generated does display "Facebook" as default-selected in my Firefox browser.

*(indented, and with `</option>` removed for legibility)*

```
<html><body><select>
<option class='solo'     value='Entry Form'>Entry Form
<option class='toplevel' value='Facebook' selected="selected">Facebook
<option class='child1'   value='Page'      >   Page
<option class='solo'     value='Single'    >      Single
<option class='solo'     value='Entry Form'>   Entry Form
<option class='solo'     value='Twitter'   >Twitter
</select></body></html>
```

The PHP test case is as follows:

```
<?php
        $formats = array(
                array('term_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Entry Form', 'slug' => 'entry-form', 'taxonomy' => 'format', 'parent' => 0),
                array('term_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Page', 'slug' => 'page', 'taxonomy' => 'format', 'parent' => 3),
                array('term_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Facebook', 'slug' => 'facebook', 'taxonomy' => 'format', 'parent' => 0),
                array('term_id' => 4, 'name' => 'Entry Form', 'slug' => 'facebook-entry-form', 'taxonomy' => 'format', 'parent' => 3),
                array('term_id' => 5, 'name' => 'Twitter', 'slug' => 'twitter', 'taxonomy' => 'format', 'parent' => 0),
                array('term_id' => 6, 'name' => 'Single', 'slug' => 'single', 'taxonomy' => 'format', 'parent' => 2),
        );

        $terms = array();
        foreach($formats as $term){
                $a = $term['parent'];
                $b = $term['term_id'];
            $terms[$a][$b] = $term;
        }

        function printTerms($terms, $parent = 0, $deep = 0, $item){
        $output = '';
    if(count($terms[$parent]) > 0){
        $indent = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $deep; $i++){
            $indent .= "   ";
        }

        foreach($terms[$parent] as $key => $term)
        {
            $selected = ($item == $term['slug']) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
            if(isset($terms[$term['term_id']]))
            {
                if($deep == 0){
                    $output .= "<option class='toplevel' value='".$term['name']."'".$selected.">".$term['name']."</option>";   //     <- Out
puts top level parents
                } else {
                    $output .= "<option class='child".$deep."' value='".$term['name']."'".$selected.">".$indent.$term['name']."</option>";
// <- Outputs children that are also parents
                }
                $output .= "\n";
                $output .= printTerms($terms, $term['term_id'], ($deep+1), $item);

            } else {
                $output .= "<option class='solo' value='".$term['name']."'".$selected.">".$indent.$term['name']."</option>";   // <- outputs
 bottom level children and solos.
                $output .= "\n";
            }
        }
    }
        return $output;
}

        print "<html><body><select>";
        print printTerms($terms, 0, 0, 'facebook');
        print "</select></body></html>";

?>
```

UPDATE: we can build on the previous `printTerms` function to do a more flexible match.

First of all we rename `printTerms()` to `printTermsBase()` and we remove from it all references to option selection. The output will then be a bunch of lines of the form

```
 <option class='something' value='somethingelse'>text</option>
```

and *now* we can run a text matching on the output. The function below, when passed "wall", will select "wall"; if no "wall" is present, it will select "facebook"; if that too isn't present it will select nothing. You may invert the array so that "wall" is selected *unless* facebook is present. Text match is exact: "facebook-form" will be ignored. If you desire to match "facebook" for "facebook-form", you need to use the `preg*` functions.

```
 function printTerms($terms, $item)
 {
     $items = array($item, 'facebook');
     $options = printTermsBase($terms, 0, 0);
     foreach($items as $raw)
     {
         // We could use preg_match here for even greater flexibility
         $search="value='$raw'";
         if (false === strpos($options, $search))
             continue;
         // One of the option matches.
         // We just replace    value='something'
         // with               value='something' selected='selected'
         return str_replace($search, $search.' selected="selected"', $options);
     }
     // No match. Return options unchanged.
     return $options;
 }
```

Comment: The thing is that $item and $term['slug'] do not always match. If item is 'wall' I want 'Facebook' to be selected by default as well. There can be several strings which could match Facebook and another set of several strings which could match Twitter. That's why my select code uses explicit string matches.

Comment: So is it possible that you have both "wall" and "Facebook" in your slugs, and, say, 'wall' is the item? For in that case you need a more thorough change on the architecture of `printTerms()`.

Comment: I sort of tried to come up with a more general solution. See updated answer.

Comment: No, the slug is only facebook but $items could be anything. If $items contains wall or facebook, then the select should be on facebook, otherwise it should be blank. See my select code to see what I'm doing with it.

Comment: Let me simplify the problem, for I am not understanding. Let's say the select is the one I posted, *without* any `selected`. Which one of the options ought to be selected (if any)?

Comment: If the variable $item[2] contains the word 'wall' or the word 'facebook', the 'facebook' option int the dropdown menu should be selected. If the $item[2] variable contains anything else, then nothing should be selected.